# WCF maxBytesPerRead limit to 4096

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I am using basic WCF web service in steaming mode to download files from server.

I have specified binding on server side as

```
     <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DBUpdateServiceBinding" closeTimeout="23:59:59"
           openTimeout="23:59:59" receiveTimeout="23:59:59" sendTimeout="23:59:59"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864" messageEncoding="Mtom"
           transferMode="Streamed">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="8192" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
```

and my client side binding xml looks like

```
  <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ws" closeTimeout="23:59:59" openTimeout="23:59:59"
           receiveTimeout="23:59:59" sendTimeout="23:59:59" maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864"
           messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="8192" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
           <security>
              <transport realm="" />
           </security>
        </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

I am trying to download files using

```
   byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
   while (true)
   {
      int read = serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      if (read <= 0)
         break;
      fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
   }
```

Even though I have specified maxBytesPerRead="8192", max bytes that I can read in a call is only 4096.

Comment: are you sure those binding configurations are really being used by your service and your client endpoint??

Comment: yes, I am sure about that. There is no other configuration defined.

Comment: is it the maxRequestLength in web.config?

Comment: What does your client creation code look like?  If you're not calling the default constructor, you're probably not using the configuration specified in app.config.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have very specific security requirements, you might want to consider setting the maximum sizes to Int32.MaxValue. It will save you some debugging time. Then tune it down to a more reasonable value if needed.

Comment: This does NOT answer the question maxBytesPerRead is stuck at 4096 no matter what you set it to (in comination with Streamed and MTOM)