# Wcf very small packet size

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

I've enabled wcf basicHttpBinding with TransferMode set to "Streaming". 
The problem is every time i do a read operation from the stream on the client side i read exactly 1536 bytes, which is an Ethernet frame.
How can i get my wcf service to send larger packets of data at a time?

**EDIT**

So, apparently the default BytesPerRead is 4096, however I've changed that value on both the client and the server. here is the config file

Moreover, I've found an unanswered post dealing with the same issue
[WCF maxBytesPerRead limit to 4096](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746638/wcf-maxbytesperread-limit-to-4096)

Server
SERVER

(Note that i have two endpoints, one is for downloading content in basicHttpBinding and one is for communication using ws2007HttpBinding, I am referring to the basicHttpBinding endpoint in my question)

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding" allowCookies="true" maxBufferSize="955366"
   maxBufferPoolSize="964285" maxReceivedMessageSize="955556" messageEncoding="Mtom"
   transferMode="Streamed">
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="60" maxStringContentLength="955556" maxArrayLength="955556"
   maxBytesPerRead="955556" maxNameTableCharCount="955556" />
  </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <ws2007HttpBinding>
  <binding name="MyBinding" allowCookies="false">
   <security mode="None" />
  </binding>
  </ws2007HttpBinding>
 </bindings>
 <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ContentManagementServiceBehavior"
  name="App_Code.Services.ContentManagement.ContentManagementService">
  <clear />
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"
   listenUriMode="Explicit" />
  <endpoint binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
   name="ws2007Endpoint" contract="App_Code.Services.ContentManagement.IContentManagementService"
   listenUriMode="Explicit" />
  <endpoint address="/download" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBinding"
   name="basicHttpBinding" contract="App_Code.Services.ContentManagement.IContentManagementDownlodService" />
  <host>
   <baseAddresses>
   <add baseAddress="/Services/ContentManagement/ContentManagementService.svc" />
   </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  </service>
 </services>
        <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="ContentManagementServiceBehavior">
   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
   <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

CLIENT

```
    <system.serviceModel>

  <bindings>

   <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"

     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"

     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"

     maxBufferPoolSize="92429000" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" messageEncoding="Mtom"

     textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">

     <readerQuotas maxDepth="90" maxStringContentLength="65536000" maxArrayLength="65536000"

      maxBytesPerRead="655360" maxNameTableCharCount="65536000" />

     <security mode="None" />

    </binding>

   </basicHttpBinding>

   <wsHttpBinding>

    <binding name="ws2007Endpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"

     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"

     transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"

     maxBufferPoolSize="524288646" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536646"

     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"

     allowCookies="false">

     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="819264564"

      maxArrayLength="163846764" maxBytesPerRead="40964543" maxNameTableCharCount="16384564" />

     <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"

      enabled="false" />

     <security mode="None">

      <transport realm="" />

     </security>

    </binding>

   </wsHttpBinding>

  </bindings>

  <client>

   <endpoint address="<absolute address>"

    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws2007Endpoint"

    contract="ContentManagementServiceReference.IContentManagementService"

    name="ws2007Endpoint" />

   <endpoint address="<absolute address>"

    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"

    contract="ContentManagementServiceReference.IContentManagementDownlodService"

    name="basicHttpBinding" />

  </client>

 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Larger packets will most probably just be fragmented; split up into several packages per 1536 bytes. Are you sure that your network can handle larger packages?

Comment: I'm sure because on a different project which I've downloaded and even uploaded files at greater speeds and in much bigger chunks using WebRequests. I'm able to download files with the speed of about 1.2mb/s and about 300-500kb/s directly from the server on which my service is hosted. Due to the processing time it takes to handle such small chunks of data (4096 bytesPerRead) download speed is between 15-30 kb/s, Which is extremely low for my connection speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e1f7b040-39a8-4ca8-9def-96b2b47c0d6f/

There are couple options there that I think will be a good fit for your issue.

Thanks,

Roberto.

Comment: The thread did fit the issue, however changing the encoding to Mtom changed the packet size to a constant 4096 bytes, is this the largest size i can expect without using some sort of binary binding?

Comment: 4096 is just the default value, and you can increase this, however if you have multiple concurrent processes streaming video (multiple clients), increasing the buffer size may become a CPU resource issue (more specifically memory).

Comment: Not true you can increase this, have you actually tried it? I wrote a basic example to do exactly that; My findings are with Text enconding max i get is 1536; with Mtom encoding max i get is 4096 (WCF hosting on IIS).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change `maxBytesPerRead` property:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Streamed" TransferMode="Streamed" TextEncoding="Mtom"
            maxMessageReceivedSize="4000000">
            <readerQuotas mexBytesPerRead="8192" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: It's already set to maxBytesPerRead="655360". I've used really high numbers on all the the binding fields using the wcf editor, doesn't seem to do anything. Reading is still stuck at 4096 bytes.

Comment: @dortzur: Did you change configuration on the client?

Comment: Yeah both the client and the server are set to a very high number. Unless there a field that isn't showing on the wcf-editor all of them are very high. I'm quite stumped at this behavior.